# Cant find file manager UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, uefi, drive

I recently installed Ubuntu on an external harddrive as MBR and wasnt visible in UEFI settings. Later some kind folks told me to convert the drive to GPT and create an ESP partition which solved my problem and now I logged into Ubuntu but I cant find my file manager.

[image: Drive error]

Comment: The file manager in standard Ubuntu Desktop is 'Files' ('Filer' in my language) alias `nautilus` when started from a terminal window). Is it there?

Comment: It was wasnt there. I apt installed it. Now its working!!. Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome :-)